# Is optical power defined for mirrors as well just as lenses?

Tags: optics, reflection, lenses

I just came across what power of a lens is and its significance.  When the optical power of a lens is defined as the ability to focus light.  Does the same apply for mirrors, too?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mirrors have optical power. Concave mirrors will have positive power and convex mirrors will have negative power.

Conceptually, the power of an optical element does relate to the ability to rapidly converge or diverge light.

Mathematically, the power is the inverse of the focal length, so something with a positive, short focal length has a large, positive power, and would bring incoming parallel rays to a point in a small distance from the lens or mirror, in the direction of the *outgoing* light, whether transmitted (for lenses) or reflected (for mirrors).